# cakephp 2.3 not returning the user's real ip

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, clientip

I am trying to use the function "clientIp", to get the real IP of the user, but this is not returning anything.
I'm using this:

```
$ipAddr = $this->request->clientIp();
print_r($ipAddr);die();
```

And print it   " ::1 "

instead of the actual ip print, print it ::1

anyone ever had this problem, how can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cakephp 2.xx

```
$this->request->clientIp();
```

You can use native PHP server variable

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

This is working example of my application on CakePhP

```
function get_realIp(){
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }elseif(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']){
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
    }
return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: I tested the 3 ways that you quoted, and the three are returning this one ::1                                                                  I'm testing this function on localhost, can it affect?

Comment: sorry you it will give you very time your local ip, you should require to test on some live ip.

Comment: I put an example on a host online, and it worked correctly.

Thank you for your help.